# UITableView in UITableViewCell passing scrolling issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

[image: UITableView inside a UITableViewCell inside a UITableView]

Blue: is a UITableView (is scrollable, only shows 4 items of the xx items)
Red: is a UITableViewCell (hides and shows blue tableview on click)
Green: is a UITableView (also scrollable)

SITUATION:

The blue tableview is perfectly scrollable when dragging. Also when I drag the cell or green table, the green table is scrollable. With a click on the cell I can expand or collapse the blue tableview.

PROBLEM:

I want when the blue tableview is at the end or the beginning of the scroll content, the scroll movement is passed to the green tableview.  Like it would be when you place a scrollview inside a scrollview.

How is this possible?
Anybody got already same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried this, but you could perhaps override `-setContentOffset:` on your inner (blue) scroll view so that it only called super when within its `contentArea`, and otherwise called `-setContentOffset:` on your outer (green) scroll view.

Comment: It seems to work indeed, but you should use `setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset` without :animated and put the inner tableview on bounce to get the movement all the time, and also some other calculations to get everything right. FYI I found another solution I guess [ExpandableRows](https://github.com/gasparenovara/ExpandableRows). Insert and delete rows.  I guess this has better performance, and maybe easier to use...